# How to make my `/usr` folder secure?

Tags: macos, security, vpn, administrator

I'm trying to install the Tunnelblick open source VPN client on my Mac running OS X 10.10.5.

When I try to install the dmg I get the following error (see attached screenshot).

[image]

How would I make my `/usr` folder secure? The account I use by default is my main user account, but also the admin account for the computer. Would it be a question of making a my main user account a standard user and setting up a separate admin account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the permissions on /usr are incorrect, which in the past has been [attributed to installing MacPorts](https://tunnelblick.net/cSystemFolderNotSecure.html). You can repair the permissions on /usr by running:

```
sudo chown root:wheel /usr
sudo chmod 0755 /usr
```

Since MacPorts installs to /opt/local, this shouldn't affect MacPorts, but as I don't use MacPorts I can't say for certain.

Comment: The standard installation dir of MacPorts is /opt/local/ or do I miss a comment deleted in the meantime!?

Comment: @klanomath I remember something about MacPorts and /usr in the past and it turns out Tunnelblick themselves also mentions MacPorts as a potential cause; I've added a link.